# validate for empty string including a space linux

Tags: bash

```
DIALOG=${DIALOG=dialog}

tempfile=`tempfile 2>/dev/null` || tempfile=/tmp/test$$
trap "rm -f $tempfile" 0 1 2 5 15                   

$DIALOG --backtitle "Search Forename" --inputbox \
    "Please enter your Forename?" 0 0 2> /tmp/inputbox.tmp.$$

retval=$?

Forename=`cat /tmp/inputbox.tmp.$$`

case $retval in
0) 
    while [[ $Forename = "" ]]; do
        $DIALOG --msgbox "Forename Cannot be left blank" 10 40;
        $DIALOG --backtitle "Search Forename" --inputbox \
           "Please enter your Forename?" 0 0 2> /tmp/inputbox.tmp.$$
        retval=$?
        Forename=`cat /tmp/inputbox.tmp.$$`
        rm -f /tmp/inputbox.tmp.$$

    done
    Forename=$(echo $Forename | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z');
    echo;
    if ! grep -Fq "Forename: $Forename" $Filename ;then
        $DIALOG --msgbox "$Forename was not found in the File" 10 40;
    else
        $DIALOG --title "Forename Results" --infobox "`grep -n "Forename: $Forename" $Filename | sort ;`" 90 120 ;
        read enterKey;
    fi
    ;;
1)
    echo "Cancel pressed.";;
esac
;;
```

the problem I am having is that the forename only validates for being empty if the user enters a space it displays all the data in the file. Could anyone suggest a way to fix this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please take time to reduce your example to the minimum required for us to reproduce the problem. Also, take care with your formatting.

Comment: Sorry I just felt it was best to show everything it was doing

Comment: Fair enough, although some effort to pinpoint the exact part of the problem is always welcome. Perhaps if all of those blank lines weren't there, the code wouldn't look so long.

Comment: @randomer: User types what, where? Which line / lines are  the one closest to the ones you're having trouble with or confused by?

Comment: its this line it only validates for empty but if i was to put blank spaces in it would display evereything in the file:                                                           while [[ $Forename = "" ]]; do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bash's regex syntax.

```
while [[ -z $Forename || $Forename =~ ^\ +$ ]]; do
    # if forename is empty or contains only whitespace
    ...
done
```

Comment: `[[ $Forename =~ ^\ *$ ]]` is enough. Or even without regex but globs: `[[ $Forename = *([[:space:]]) ]]`